# I "import caffe" from ipython, but I got "RuntimeWarning". How to resolve it?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I have read the article "Ubuntu Installation --Guide for Ubuntu 14.04 with a 64 bit processor." from Github website (https://github.com/tiangolo/caffe/blob/ubuntu-tutorial-b/docs/install_apt2.md).
And now, I open IPython to test that PyCaffe is working. I input "ipython" command, and enter to the ipython page.

Then, I input the command "import caffe", but I got below warnings:

> /root/code/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py:13:RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr > already registered; second conversion method ignored. from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
>
> /root/code/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py:13: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr > already registered; second conversion method ignored. from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
>
> /root/code/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py:13: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr > already registered; second conversion method ignored. from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \

Would you please help to give me some suggestions to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/C_air48cISU

Claiming that this is a non-error, cause by mis-matched versions of Boost.  You can safely ignore it.  They've promised to clean up the warning (at some point not yet specified)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit /caffe/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp . There are four places need to change,like this

```
bp::register_ptr_to_python<shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > >();
```

to

```
const boost::python::type_info cinfo = boost::python::type_id<shared_ptr<Blob<Dtype> > >();
const boost::python::converter::registration* creg = boost::python::converter::registry::query(cinfo);
      if (creg == NULL)
      {
         bp::register_ptr_to_python<shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > >();
      }
      else if ((*creg).m_to_python == NULL) {
         bp::register_ptr_to_python<shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > >();
      }
```

then compile use 'make pycaffe' ,it will be ok.